# Error using the 'find' command to generate a collection file on opencv

Tags: opencv, cmd, cascade, haar-classifier

I am facing a problem generating a collection file of the positive images to train the Haar Cascade in OpenCV to detect a car. On every tutorial I found on the internet, it is the same command, however i am unable to execute it.
I am using Command Prompt and Windows Power Shell to execute this command.    `find ./positive_images/ -iname '.*pgm' > positives.txt` [the screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UfFx.png)     I am running this command from root of my directory. The positive images are stored in `positive_images` folder.

**OUTPUT**:

`File not found - '*pgm'`

However, the `positive_images` directory contains 550 files with `.pgm` extension.

Comment: Please edit the question to include your output directly (as text).

Comment: @D.U here's the link to the tutorial i'm following. [ Coding Robin](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html). I am new to OpenCV and trying Car Detection algorithm using Cascade Classifier. I have a Data set of positive and negative images.
Also, every tutorial i found usses this method.

Comment: @D.U even if we follow the official documentation, i am unable to find steps to create the `directory file`  that is the `bg.txt` as given in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Error `File not found - '*pgm'`

> I am using Command Prompt and Windows Power Shell to execute this command:
>
> ```
> find ./positive_images/ -iname '.*pgm' > positives.txt
> ```

The above command is using the syntax of a Unix version of `find`, but you are running it under Windows. PowerShell does not have a built in `find` command so you are running `C:\Windows\System32\find.exe`.

Notes:

- Unix `find` is used to search for files.
- Windows `find` is used to search for string in files.

As you are running on Windows you need to use `dir` instead of `find`:

```
dir /b /s positive_images\*.pgm > positives.txt
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.

Comment: Sorry! Must have been a mistake. Your solution helped me resolve my problem as I stated earlier. :) There is no reason to unaccept it,

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)